# Set a session hash outside of RoR program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2

I have had my new rails program up for a few days now. I'm running it on
Ubuntu 10.4 with apache2 in another location than the website it's made
for (it's a standalone database application for physiotherapists). The
people I made it for now want me to deploy it to the public part of
their website, only with one change. Those who open it via the link in
the public-part should not be able to click one button!

I was thinking of doing something like this in my view:

```
<% if session[:inside]%>
  <%=button_to 'Sækja mælitæki', @link_to_mt%>
<%end%>
```

How could I set session[:inside] only to true if the program was started
from within the private part of the webpage? I thought of creating two
new actions, the other would set session[:inside] to true and the other
to false, but that seems to me like a security risk, is it not?

BR,
Sindri

Comment: What is private part and public part? Are those are controllers or what?

Comment: The private and public part are not part of my program, but another website that should link to my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the referer.
Notice that this is not a bulletproof solution and there are many plugins (e.g. for firefox) which delete the referer from every request.

```
<% if request.referer.start_with? "your.internal.site" %>
    <%=button_to 'Sækja mælitæki', @link_to_mt%>
<%end%>
```

What does the button do? Is it a big security risk if it's visible by accident?

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I'd imagine I can use this code in the controller to set a cookie and then render the button if the cookie is set, so that it would be visible if the user navigates to somewhere else on my page, going to try it out :)
It's both a security and aesthetic problem, this button allows people to download pdf-files which only people who have internal access to the referrer page should be able to get, but I'm also controlling the download with another controller, so I think I'm safe ;)